# rename files inside a folder in real time

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, cron

Is there a way to rename files inside a folder as they're created?

I could run a cron job every few seconds to do something like...

`find . -name "file.*" -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/file.*\$/"file-$(date).*"/)"' _ {} \;`

but this seems really cumbersome, cycle-wise...

Comment: FYI, cron can't go faster than once a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a framework in Linux called `inotify` which allows a program to register a handler to be called each time a file or a directory changes, so if you're writing a C program you can just use that. Obviously, your program will need to be running when the change occurs.

There is a special daemon called [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) which is like "cron for inotify" and is able to run scripts when a file/directory changes. It can be installed with `sudo apt-get install incron`, then you'll need add a few lines to its configuration file.

Here's a helpful article: [Linux incrond inotify: Monitor Directories For Changes And Take Action](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/)

If you search synaptic for "inotify" you'll find many more libraries and programs with similar functionality.

Comment: inotify has a more direct command line wrapper, but incron appears to be easier to use.

Comment: incron is pretty amazing, I will post my full solution once I get it working, thanks

Comment: this is very odd, so I thought I had it working...I was able to create a simple test with my user account (not root), since the files I want to change are in my home dir. Anyways, so `incrontab -e` to open up the config, I set up `~/ IN_CREATE touch ~/test`, so I navigated to ~/, and ran `>foo`, then `test` appeared, yay!  So now I'm getting a little more complicated and trying a shell script, so now I have... `~/ IN_CREATE ~/test.sh`, the contents of the shell script are: `#!/bin/sh touch test`, this is not working for whatever reason...

Comment: Hmmm, so I started receiving `bash: fork, cannot allocate memory` errors, and looked at ps aux, it was full of my script trying to run and eating my memory up! Not sure what happened, but I have it under control now...

Answer (score 1):

So, using [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), I set it up by running `sudo apt-get install incron`.

My goal: Allow emails with picture attachments sent to an alias (sendtodropbox.com app) to be automatically copied into my blog's photo repository for posting.

Next I created a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls photo.JPG | while read a; do mv $a "$(echo "$a" | sed s/photo.JPG/"photo$(date +%a%b%d%H%M).jpg"/)"; done
mv photo* ~/Dropbox/Attachments /<photo repo>/
```

I place the script in `~/`, then edit the `/etc/incron.allow` file to include my user name because these scripts and files are all in my home dir. Next I have to edit the incron config file by running `incrontab -e`.

In here I used `~/Dropbox/Attachments/ IN_MOVED_TO ~/script.sh` (I used IN_MOVED_TO because the action of Dropbox placing a file in the Dropbox folder is considered a move)

This is working instantaneously when I email my Dropbox a picture from my phone now. I also tested incron with both root and my user name to make sure it worked, my first test as my user was: `incrontab -e` add the config: `~/ IN_CREATE touch ~/test`, I then go to `~/`, and run `>foo`, and `test` appears.

Comment: I should note that, while it probably works in your specific case, the general rule is to never parse the output of `ls`. It can easily cause breakage when filenames include spaces or other "special" characters. Use shell globs instead. For example, `for f in some_directory; do echo "now processing $f"; done` It's simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Oops. `for f in some_directory/*; do echo "Processing some_directory/$f..."; done`  I missed the all-important glob in my earlier comment, and it appears to be too late to edit it.